# i need some assistance with my python pyglatin code

Tags: python

ok so the code is

```
pyg = 'ay'
print "To translate type A SINGLE word or name!"
original = raw_input("Type word Here:")
while len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    new_word = word[1:] + first + pyg
    print "Translating 1 moment..."
    print "Translated view below!"
    print new_word
    print "Made by: Tobias Balentine"
    raw_input ('pause')
    if raw_input ("Do you want to start over?").lower().[0] != 'y': break
```

so my question is how do i restart to the start of the code without exiting the program  when i put `(if raw_input ("Do you want to start over?").lower().[0] != 'y': break)` it just shows the translation again but i want it to go to the start of the code so you can type a different word to translate how would i go about doing this?

P.S. i am new to python

Comment: Your word prompt isn't inside the loop.

Comment: well can you tell me how to fix it cuz i am new to python

Comment: Understanding what a loop does is a fundamental part of any programming language. I recommend looking up some Python tutorials to get a handle on the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this statement:

```
original = raw_input("Type word Here:")
```

inside your while statement. Your final code should be like this:

```
pyg = 'ay'
print "To translate type A SINGLE word or name!"
original = raw_input("Type word Here:")
while len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    new_word = word[1:] + first + pyg
    print "Translating 1 moment..."
    print "Translated view below!"
    print new_word
    print "Made by: Tobias Balentine"
    raw_input ('pause')
    if raw_input ("Do you want to start over?").lower().[0] != 'y':
        break
    original = raw_input("Type word Here:")
```

Comment: you'll need to define `original` above the loop

Comment: well i does work semi because when i run the program the first time it makes me type the name twice instead of once

Comment: Type word Here:tobias
Type word Here:tobias
Translating 1 moment...
Translated view below!
obiastay
Made by: Tobias Balentine
pause
Do you want to start over?

Comment: @Tobias, Woops. Didn't notice that. This should fix that

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, if you want to continually prompt the user for new words, you need to have that prompt be inside of the loop. You could do something like this, where you prompt the user in the loop, and then, if the input is valid, translate the word. If it's not, tell the user so. Then, in either case, you ask the user if she wants to start over, and break the loop if she doesn't say yes (or more accurately, if she types anything that doesn't start with a "Y" or "y").

```
pyg = 'ay'
print "To translate type A SINGLE word or name!"
while True:
    original = raw_input("Type word Here:")

    # Validate the input here. If it's valid, 
    # do the translation.
    if original and original.isalpha():  
        word = original.lower()
        first = word[0]
        new_word = word[1:] + first + pyg
        print "Translating 1 moment..."
        print "Translated view below!"
        print new_word
    else:
        # Tell the user if his input is invalid. 
        print "Your input was stupid. No translation 4 u."

    # Ask the user if he wants to start over
    if raw_input ("Do you want to start over?").lower()[0] != 'y': 
        break

# Give em something to remember you by
print "Made by: Tobias Balentine"
```